# adding icon to the jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding the validation to the tabs i have and they work fine, my only concern is: if all 3 tabs have errors as of now, the last tab is displayed because the last tab has error

```
function verify() {
   var istab1error = $("#div").hasClass('udf-error);
   var istab2error = $("#div1").hasClass('udf-error);
   var istab3error = $("#div2").hasClass('udf-error);
   if(istab1error) {
      $(this).tabs({selected:0});
   }
   if(istab2error) {
      $(this).tabs({selected:1});
   }
   if(istab3error) {
      $(this).tabs({selected:2});
   }
}
```

and that way i always get last tab if the last tab has error too, the other two tabs have error but they are not selected.

i want them to show them by order

Comment: Are you missing a single quote somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were missing some single quotes.  This should work better.

```
function verify() {
   var istab1error = $("#div").hasClass('udf-error');
   var istab2error = $("#div1").hasClass('udf-error');
   var istab3error = $("#div2").hasClass('udf-error');
   if(istab1error) {
      $(this).tabs({selected:0});
   }
   if(istab2error) {
      $(this).tabs({selected:1});
   }
   if(istab3error) {
      $(this).tabs({selected:2});
   }
}
```